# dividir 1 coluna em 2 no sql server dando update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Utilizo o SQL Server 2012

Tenho o seguinte problema, em uma tabela existem registros de municípios e duas respectivas UFs porém surge a necessidade de dividir esta coluna em 2 uma de município e uma de UF, mas os dados estão deste jeito:

```
CANDÓI-PR
VERÊ-PR
NAO-ME-TOQUE-RS
NAO-ME-TOQUE / RS
SERTAO / RS
JABOTICABA/RS
VERÊ
```

Sendo assim se alguém puder criar um código que separe esta em 2 e fazendo um UPDATE na original, levando em consideração que não existe um padrão na coluna por exemplo existe '/' '-' e existem alguns sem UFs que devem retornar NULL

tentei o seguinte código:

```
select 
    case when CHARINDEX('-',[MUNICIPIO / UF])>0 
         then SUBSTRING([MUNICIPIO / UF],1,CHARINDEX('-',[MUNICIPIO / UF])-1) 
         else [MUNICIPIO / UF] end Municipio, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',[MUNICIPIO / UF])>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING([MUNICIPIO / UF],CHARINDEX('-',[MUNICIPIO / UF])+1,len([MUNICIPIO / UF]))  
         ELSE NULL END as UF
from TABLE
UNION all
select 
    case when CHARINDEX('/',[MUNICIPIO / UF])>0 
         then SUBSTRING([MUNICIPIO / UF],1,CHARINDEX('/',[MUNICIPIO / UF])-1) 
         else [MUNICIPIO / UF] end Municipio, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('/',[MUNICIPIO / UF])>0 
         THEN SUBSTRING([MUNICIPIO / UF],CHARINDEX('/',[MUNICIPIO / UF])+1,len([MUNICIPIO / UF]))  
         ELSE NULL END as UF
from TABLE
```

Eles funcionam separados mas juntos retornam valores duplicados e o distinct não ajuda pois realmente existem valores iguais na tabela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente esse script...

```
CREATE TABLE #TMP_CIDADES
(
    [MUNICIPIO / UF] varchar(max) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('CANDÓI-PR')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('VERÊ-PR')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('NAO-ME-TOQUE-RS')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('NAO-ME-TOQUE / RS')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('SERTAO / RS')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('JABOTICABA/RS')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('VERÊ')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('VERÊ NOVA    - SP')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('VERÊ VELHA     / RJ')
INSERT INTO #TMP_CIDADES ([MUNICIPIO / UF]) VALUES ('VERÊ      -        AM')

DECLARE @LETRAS_ESTADOS varchar(26) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([MUNICIPIO / UF], ' ', '')), 3, 1) ,@LETRAS_ESTADOS) = 0 THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([MUNICIPIO / UF], ' ', '')), 1, 3)), '-', ''), '/', '') ELSE NULL END ESTADO
    ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([MUNICIPIO / UF], ' ', '')), 3, 1) ,@LETRAS_ESTADOS) = 0 THEN SUBSTRING([MUNICIPIO / UF], 1, CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(REPLACE([MUNICIPIO / UF], ' ', '')), 3, 1),[MUNICIPIO / UF]) - 1) ELSE [MUNICIPIO / UF] END CIDADE
FROM #TMP_CIDADES

DROP TABLE #TMP_CIDADES
```

Com a TEMP Carregada e após conferir as conversões, você poderá proceder seu update a partir dela.

Comment: cara obrigado! ficou faltando um caso que só vi agora onde o aparece VERÊ RS, só com o espaço mas ele eu resolvo!